# Scaling and then Scaling Back in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode, scale

I want to be able to scale things in Edit Mode, like by .1 for instance.  Then I want to be able to scale it back again to its original size.
The problem is I don't know how to figure out what I need to scale it by the second time to get it back to its original size. xD
Would someone enlighten me? :D

Comment: To go back you do 1/x where x is what you scaled by the first time.. For example 0.1 -> 1/0.1 = 10

Comment: Thanks man!  Post as an answer and I'll give you credit for your math wizardry! xD